# MCTS 70-515 training kit, wrong on view state?

Tags: asp.net, web

On page 123 of the book - chapter 3, lesson 2. it says: 
"
The Page.ViewState property provides a dictionary object for retaining values between
multiple requests for the same page. This object is of the type StateBag. When an ASP.NET
page is processed, the current state of the page and its controls is hashed into a string and
saved in the page as an HTML hidden field called __ViewState. If the data is too long for a
single field (as specified in the Page.MaxPageStateFieldLength property), ASP.NET performs
view state chunking to split it across multiple hidden fields."

my understanding of the __ViewState hidden field is that it stores the values of controls changed when compared to what they were at design time. Not to mention that if __ViewState was a hash of any amount of data it would never get too large since hashes are fixed in size.

Is the book wrong? or am i missing something here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewstate is encoded with base-64.

Book is misleading because hashing is one-way operation and it would make pretty impossible to decode it later on the server side.

Your understanding is also wrong, viewstate is not storing values different from design-time values. Basically, it is persisting form data between postbacks. Please refer to msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx) for detailed info.

Answer (score 1):

I am also studying for this exam using the same book. That particular line seems similar to the information in the following article

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/75x4ha6s.aspx
>
> When the page is processed, the current state of the page and controls
>   is hashed into a string and saved in the page as a hidden field, or
>   multiple hidden fields if the amount of data stored in the ViewState
>   property exceeds the specified value in the MaxPageStateFieldLength
>   property. When the page is posted back to the server, the page parses
>   the view-state string at page initialization and restores property
>   information in the page.

However, if you dig elsewhere on MSDN, one gets following explanation which is accurate.

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bb386448.aspx
>
> By default, view state data is stored in the page in a hidden field
>   and is encoded using base64 encoding. In addition, a hash of the view
>   state data is created from the data by using a machine authentication
>   code (MAC) key. The hash value is added to the encoded view state data
>   and the resulting string is stored in the page. When the page is
>   posted back to the server, the ASP.NET page framework re-computes the
>   hash value and compares it with the value stored in view state. If the
>   hash values do not match, an exception is raised that indicates that
>   view state data might be invalid.
>
> By creating a hash value, the ASP.NET page framework can test whether
>   the view state data has been corrupted or tampered with. However, even
>   if it is not tampered with, view state data can still be intercepted
>   and read by malicious users.

So, to answer your questions.

- Hashing is done but for validity purposes only. That paragraph is certainly misleading.
- Regarding __ViewState, Dooh has provided the link above